# React Native getInitialState() syntax error (unexpected token)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I can't seem to figure out why this code gives me a syntax/unexpected token error on line 14. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm pretty sure that getInitialState() is set up correctly and not sure why it's throwing an error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends Component {
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      test: ''
    };
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          {this.state.test}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Test', () => Test);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing ES5 way of writing react components with ES6(ES2015) way of writing react components. Read more about it here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html

To Fix your code, modify as below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
      test: ''
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          {this.state.test}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Test', () => Test);
```